# Iterating through the parameters in csv file and run pipeline with each parameter

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Hi i have a scenario where i have an csv file in azure datalake storage. while running azure pipeline, the parameters from the excel has to be picked up one by one in an iterative manner. Based on each parameter the databricks notebook should be run.

Is there any solution for this - how to iterate through the values in csv file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Azure, you should consider Azure Data Factory (ADF) or Azure Synapse Analytics which has pipelines.  Both are good for moving data from place to place and data orchestration.  For example you could have an ADF pipeline with a Lookup activity which reads your .csv, then calls a For Each activity with a parameterised Databricks notebook inside:

[image: ADF pattern]

Interestingly, the For Each activity runs in parallel so could deal with multiple lines at once, depending on your Databricks cluster size etc.

You could try and do all this within a single Databricks notebook which I'm sure is possible, but I would say that is a more code heavy approach and you still have questions around the scheduling, doing tasks in parallel, orchestration etc